# FOSUserBundle - Overriding forms: how does one actually add the Registration validation group?

Tags: php, symfony

The [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) mention it in passing, but without an example.  Do I need to make a new validation.yml file?  Add to the existing config.yml?  And what would I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the default options in the form type

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                [...],
                'validation_groups' => array(
                        'Registration'
                ),
        ));
}
```